# Tinybrowser Error 403 on Upload Completion

Tags: php, .htaccess, tinymce

I am trying to get Tinybrowser version 1.42 working and keep running into problems. I was able to get as far as actually being able to upload images (access the Upload tab, browse for the file, watch as it uploaded) but now I am receiving a Status: 403 error message after the upload reaches 100%.

Tinybrowser created the proper directories and they are set to 775, even though the progress bar goes to 100% on upload, nothing is being uploaded.

I found in troubleshooting that I should create an .htaccess file in the "tinybrowser directory" (I assume this is the main directory for the plugin?) with the following contents - this results in an Error 500:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

Anyone have any idea how to make this work? I never had this much trouble with past versions

Comment: Hasn't anyone else had this problem? I attempted to contact the developer and also have not heard back from them. Trying everything I can think of here and cannot make any progress.. any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: 403 stands for Forbidden. Did you add password protection to the site?

Comment: No. Have a deadline for this project and wasted hours trying to figure this out, opted to just go with CKEditor and CKFinder instead.. the license is much more expensive but it works. Still curious what is going on with all these glitches, though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes 403 stands for Forbidden.

I face the same problem. After a lot of research i found that some server security is set ON
which blocks the upload.php to upload any image/file. So turn OFF the security stuff and it works.

Hope this will

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.